# How to insert string to subprocess output with keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

How can I insert my string while the subprocess is running so I can make an indictation of a record? Currently the "q" key does nothing to interrupt the loop. I can see the output of the tcpdump command but "Probe Marked" doesn't make it through.

```
import keyboard
import subprocess as sub

p = sub.Popen(("/usr/bin/pkexec", "sudo", "tcpdump", "-i", "wlan0mon", "-e", "-s", "256", "type", "mgt", "subtype", "probe-resp", "or", "subtype", "probe-req"), stdout=sub.PIPE)
for row in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''): # "readahead buffer" bug
    print(row.rstrip())
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed
        print("Probe Marked")
        break
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `p.stdout.readline(` and not `p.stdin.readline(` instead? Or `p.stdout.writeline(`. But the loop doesn't make much sense anyway, unless there's more info you can provide

Comment: @Pynchia It works to output the command to the screen which is the intended result of that part of the loop. The loop is supposed to run indefinitely, with output pausing for a moment to insert the string "Probe Marked" into the output when the "q" button is pressed, then continuing the shell command.